# Underscore templage passted variable access in template script code

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette, underscore.js-templating

I have a Marionette view in which I am rendering the view like :

```
         var template = _.template(RequestorFormTemplate);
         $(this.el).html(template({fdata:fdata}));
```

In the template (html) I have a java script where I need to access fdata. How do I access the variable in script. I know we can access this in HTML like <%=%> but can I access this in script.

Comment: Are you saying you have <script>//js code</script> in your html template? What would be the point of that?

Comment: Yeah, I had the same thought. I moved the JS code to view but there is a function $.plot which seems to be unavailable in Marionette view. I am not very expert at JavaScript. Not sure of how to handle the script in view I moved it to html. You are correct - I should have all JS in view but not sure how to resolve $.plot (function) which is not accessible.

Comment: You should be able to find a way so that method can be used in the view. I don't think that script tags in templates even work.

Comment: Yeah - Looking into it. But script does work in template, it is invoking JS function and rendering the graph.

Comment: $.plot($("#bar-chart"), ds, {
                colors : [$chrt_second, $chrt_fourth, "#666", "#BBB"],
                grid : {
                    show : true,
                    hoverable : true,
                    clickable : true,
                    tickColor : $chrt_border_color,
                    borderWidth : 0,
                    borderColor : $chrt_border_color,
                },

Comment: maybe the problem is that you're calling $.plot before the proper script loads. You could try using settimeout or $(document).ready() and see if it works then

Comment: Above is what I am not able to access.

Comment: I am using AMD to modularize the code. does the load script work same putting required js in define block.

Comment: I did load this with requireJS in AMD and seems that at least $.plot error is gone. Still trying to make this work, will post the updates.

Comment: Got to work on it today. Thanks for pointing to right usage. I got this working now - one thing that I found is in order for plot function to be work for graph, div needs to be already rendered. Now thats the challenge at the moment that graph can;t be plotted in view, i am currently plotting this in parent view.

Comment: As it sounds like you already discovered, using jQuery plugins requires the view to be rendered.  The best practice is to put all commands for calling jQuery plugins on the view's `onRender()` method.

Comment: Thanks everyone for great pointers, I experimented this with data table as well which seems to be DOM dependent plugin and I used onShow method to render the table correctly. Will attempt the onRender (which I am assuming similar to onShow) on next try. Thanks again!!